# Angular2 ngFor ajuda com loop

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript, angular2-http

Tenho um arquivo `nvi.json` que está desta forma:

```
[
     {
    "abbrev": "gn",
    "book": "Gênesis",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "1": {
          "1": "...",
          "2": "..."
        }
      },
      {
        "2": {
          "1": "...",
          "2": "..."
        }
      },
      {
        "3": {
          "1": "...",
          "2": "..."
        }
      }
     ]
     }
    ]
```

E estou acessando assim:

```
export class BookPage {
    public chapters: Array<string>;
    private url: any = "../../assets/nvi.json";

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private NavParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {
    let id = NavParams.get('id');

    this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.chapters = data[id].chapters[0];
        console.log(this.chapters);
      });
      }
```

`this.chapters` retorna o primeiro capítulo onde contem os versículos, mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer um `loop` destes versículos.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of chapters">
     {{item}}
    </div>
```

Console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./BookPage class BookPage - inline template:33:5 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.      NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Comment: *ngFor="let item of chapters"

Comment: Obrigado pela observação! eu postei via celular e com isso muitos erros de digitação.

Comment: Os chapters estão organizados de uma forma que o angular não consegue ler ["1":{object}, "2":{object}] você precisa deixar um array só de objects [{object},{object}]

Comment: de {
    "1": {
      "1": "...",
      "2": "..."
    }
  }
seria melhor enviar do backend
 {
    "1": [{chapter:1, ....} , {chapter:2, ....}]
  }

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que pude simular aqui seu problema esta em JavaScript puro, veja o json é um objeto ou seja ainda que pareça um array aninhado ele não está neste formato.

Veja como transformar um objeto em array:

```
var obj = {1: 11, 2: 22};
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
```

no caso o objeto que você está expondo chapters no mínimo ele deveria passar por um processo como este:

```
var arr = Object.keys(chapters[1]).map(function (key) { return chapters[1][key]; });
```

e mais uma coisa não adianta você definir o tipo de variável e depois setar um valor de tipo diferente o que prevalecerá será o ultimo tipo setado.

```
public chapters: Array<string>;
...
this.chapters = data[id].chapters[0];
```

Ao fazer isso `chapters` passará a ser um objeto não um array.
faça um `console.log(chapters);` e observe bem este objeto no console, com os dados reais será mais fácil você ver o comportamento.

Espero ter ajudado.

Um Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Caso não consiga mexer na estrutura desse JSON para transformá-lo em um array, use o keyvalue pipe do Angular: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of chapters | keyvalue">
    {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```